# Alchemy News API - How to retrieve full text of a article?

Tags: alchemyapi

The field "enriched.url.text" returns only snippet of a article.But the documentation says it has full text and it is searchable i'm not able to understand it clearly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The AlchemyData News API is deprecated (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-data-news.html) and in its place is Watson Discovery News (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery.html).

To migrate to Watson Discovery, IBM has a document here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/migrate-adn.html

According to the documentation: "the query structure and the structure of data returned is different between Watson Discovery News and AlchemyData News. It is recommended that you query for a single result in Watson Discovery News to view how the data is structured."

If you're still working on this question, the best approach would be to migrate to the Discovery API and then run some test queries to verify you get back the full text for "enriched.url.text" intended.